# akka http getFromFile add headers

Tags: http-headers, akka-http

How can I add extra response headers when using akka-http getFromFile method. Having route like this:

```
path("image.jpg")  {
        var f = new File("/path/to/image.jpg")
        getFromFile(f,ContentType(MediaTypes.`image/jpeg`))
      } ~
```

I want to add this header:

```
RawHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `respondWithHeader` directive, e.g.

```
  val route =
    (path("image.jpg") & respondWithHeader(RawHeader("myheader", "myvalue"))) {
      val f = new File("/path/to/image.jpg")
      getFromFile(f, ContentType(MediaTypes.`image/jpeg`))
    }
```

Comment: It works fine thanks. Is there a better way to serve images with akka-http ?

Comment: AFAIK that's the way to go. Alternatively: `getFromResource` if it's more convenient

Comment: For some reason HttpResonse header is missing Content-Type now.